# Slow file delete file from asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I delete any file from an asp.net mvc project (project not in svn or any source control provider) it takes upto 60 seconds for the UI to become responsive again. CPU usage jumps to 80/90%.
Has anyone else experienced this and know of any fix or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I had similar issue.
Just empty your recycle bin and it'll start deleting files snappy again.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean deleting a file from Visual Studio solution?  If so, the fix is to empty your Windows recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the running website trying to delete a file, then do your file delete in a separate thread.

If you're talking about deleting a source file, I have had that problem a few years ago.  I don't remember what the fix was, but I don't think it's in the latest Visual Studio (which you're probably using if your doing MVC)

Comment: Nope this is in 'design' mode.